# React native - Duplicate class found in android module

Tags: android, react-native

My react native project was working fine, then all of a sudden I started getting the following error when I run the app on the simulator or build the project from android studio.

### Error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbl found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0)
```

### React Native Info

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 1.22 GB / 11.86 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.8 - F:\app\numu\node_modules\.bin\npm.CMD
    Watchman: 20200726.234435.0 - G:\watchman-v2020.07.27.00-windows\bin\watchman.EXE
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  4.0.0.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
    react-native: 0.60.0 => 0.60.0
```

### What I've Tried

- Tried [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12723#issuecomment-612490322) github comment.
- Clean Project (Android Studio)
- Invalidate caches / Restart (Android Studio)
- watchman watch-del-all
- Removed and reinstalled npm packages
- Deleted android build folder
- ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `react-native-camera` / `react-native-qrcode-scanner` libraries and I think this has something to do with mlkit migration and has nothing to do with the new version of gradle (correct me if I'm wrong, still looking for an explanation for this).

in `build.gradle`, in `android` -> under `defaultConfig`

`missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'`

Solution:

`missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'`

Comment: I uninstalled Android Studio and installed latest version, updated gradle version, cleaned android project, deleted node_modules and reinstalled npm packages and this worked for me

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean missingDimensionStrategy with 'general' option?

Comment: You can find it [here](https://react-native-camera.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation#android-other-required-steps)

Comment: @Lubbo it means that when android encounter react-native-camera, then it should select general flavor. see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies